# Ubuntuをインストール後再起動したらGUIが崩れました

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Ubuntu 20.04.1を導入し、最初から表示は正常でしたが、再起動してみたら、デスクトップの背景も青く、アイコンも表示されなく、設定メニューも表示されません。どこから原因を探し始めれば宜しいでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 最新版というと、20.10でしょうか？再度インストールを行ってみたり、安定版の20.04をインストールしてどうなるかを調べてみてはいかがでしょうか

Comment: @PicoSushi 御返事に感謝します。20.04.1で御座います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

同じ症状になったことが無いので適当な回答になりますが、まずはもう一度再起動してみてください。それで駄目なら、HDDやSSDが正常かどうかチェックされてはどうでしょう？

正常かどうかには、物理的に正常に動くかどうか（HDD等の寿命関係の調査）と、ケーブル類がきちんと接続されているか、電源は問題無いかなども含みます。
文字は出ているのにアイコンや壁紙等のアセットが全く表示されていないので、アセット等が物理的に読み込めなくなっている可能性があるかもしれません。（ただ、それだと設定メニュー自体は開きそうな気もするんですよね）

HDD等に問題無い場合は私ならOSを再インストールしますが、もしそれでも同じ症状が出るなら、Ubuntuのイメージファイルに問題がある可能性があるので、最新（もしくは、少し前の安定板）のイメージファイルを再ダウンロードしてやり直すと思います。

なお、これは仮想環境の場合は考慮していません。
また、セキュリティは適切に設定してあるものとして考えています。

Comment: 御回答に感謝します。再インストールしてみたら、直りましたが、このエラー永遠に謎になってしまいました・・・

Comment: 再インストールで直ったということですので、ドライブがちょっと怪しい気がしますね。もしくは、システム更新時にエラーで破損かどちらかかな・・・。同じ症状では無いですが、Ubuntuがおかしくなった時にこの２つのケースはどちらも起こったことがあります。